# How to filter different values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to  filter from a Table [Sales] some values with a SQL instruction.
My table has Date, ID and Sales.

So I filter it for when Date is after 01/01/2017, but I also want to filter to exclude some "Id", right now I only can filter to one, or to exclude just one, how do I do it, if I want to Filter
Id 12,53,68,98 and 150.

This is the one I got right now.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sales]
WHERE Date >= "20170101" AND Id = 12
```

Or

```
WHERE Date >= "20170101" AND Id <> 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sales]
WHERE Date >= "20170101" 
AND Id IN (12,53,68,98,150)
```

OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sales]
WHERE Date >= "20170101" 
AND Id NOT IN (12,53,68,98,150)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM [Sales] WHERE Date >= "20170101" AND Id NOT IN (12,53,68,98)
```

Good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Use "IN" like:

```
WHERE .... AND Id IN (X, Y, Z, ...)
```

Where x, y, z, ... are comma-seperated values. You can use the same statement with NOT to exclude values:

```
WHERE .... AND Id NOT IN (X, Y, Z, ...)
```